# limiting incoming database value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want an advice in `MYSql workbench` process.

Is there any way so that I can discard the incoming values after a certain number of rows have been filled with values in the table.

For example, I have to keep a limit of 500  rows so that after that even if there are incoming values from the remote server they will not be added in my database.

I added the limit to the rows but it doesn't shows the rows more than 500 but the values are still being added to my database.

Is there any way to discard incoming value in the database after a certain limit has reached?

Comment: Not out of box, you'll have to write some sort of an external process that will do cleanup and delete messages based on certain criteria.

Comment: the values will come from a jar file which is scheduled to run after one hour.is there any method so that we can stop those jar files for a certain period of time using cron?